# Is this a group on the circle?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a way the set of real points on any circle be made into a group?
I was trying to form a group from the real points of a circle as below:

- The identity element will be the point $(0,1)$.
- To find the product of any two points $A$ and $B$, draw a straight line through them (so we have the line $\overline{AB}$), then draw a line parallel to $\overline{AB}$ that passes through $(0,1)$, the identity point. The point where it intersects the circle is the product of $A$ and $B$.
- The inverse of any point is the point directly opposite that point horizontally. Example the inverse of the point $(1,0)$ is the point $(-1,0)$. With this setting, we see the inverse of the identity $(0,1)$ is itself. Also, the inverse of the $(0,-1)$ is itself.

Comment: Not sure of your construction, but the answer to your question is yes:  t's the group of planar rotations.  (rotate the vector $(0,1)$, or whatever, to the chosen vector.

Comment: The product of an element and its inverse isn't the identity in your construction..

Comment: The product of an element and its inverse is the identity because the line connecting them is parallel to (0,1) if we made a line that passes through it. and since no other point in the circle that intersects the line that passes through (0,1) but (0,1) itself!

Comment: In this construction, the product of A and B may have two possible values

Comment: Is your product associative?  That requires proof.  What is the square of an element?  What, for example, is $(1,0)\times (1,0)$?  Is it $(0,-1)$?  That seems the most natural.  But then...Well, look at $A=(1,0),B=(-1,0)$.  Clearly $A(AB)=Ae=A$, yes?  But $(AA)B=(0,-1)\times (-1,0)$ which does not appear to be $A$.  Have I blundered?  If not, that would be a failure of associativity.

Comment: @lulu I dont know if its associative, but i saw a way to attack it I just cant prove it right now. (1,0)x(1,0)=(0,-1) because the line connecting (1,0) and (1,0) is the tangent line parallel the y axis and since the point of intersection of the line that passes the identity and which is parallel to the tangent line is (0,-1) is indeed the product. and (AA)B=(0,-1)x(-1,0)=A, because the line parallel to the line that connects (0,-1) and (-1,0) that passes through the identity is (1,0), which is A. You may want to draw it to see it.

Comment: @lulu Actually, $(0,-1)\times(-1,0)$ will be exectly $(1,0)=A$, so it seems to be finde. If I am not mistaken of course.

Comment: @M.Winter  I think you are right.  I had an error in my picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed a group!

Moreover, this same group structure can be put onto any conic -- not just a circle. The reason why this is a group and why this works with conics is due to where the proof for associativity comes from: [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem). As you have already discovered, the rest of the group axioms come more-or-less for free from the definition of the operation.

You may be interested in two papers on the subject:

- F. Lemmermeyers' [*Conics -- A Poor Man's Elliptic Curves*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311306.pdf)
- S. Shirali's [*Groups Associated with Conics*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/40378668.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A5877d85ab650659b628c3e77c3336337)

As you will see in Lemmermeyers' paper, you can endow elliptic curves with a similar structure. You can read more about the elliptic curve group [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) or [here](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf). The group is also mentioned in some algebraic geometry texts as well.

Edit: N. J. Wildberger [mentions this group](https://youtu.be/-ypicun4AbM?list=PL41FDABC6AA085E78) in a lecture of his on Algebraic Topology and talks some about the proof of associativity.

Comment: The group can't be cyclic because it is uncountable. The group is just too large to be generated by a single element.

Comment: but if we take proper subgroups, we can always have a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: If you consider the subgroup of rational points on the circle, this is not a cyclic group.

Comment: Not sure about that because I can always construct a cyclic group from an arbitrary starting point close to the identity point.

Comment: You can create many cyclic subgroups, but not all subgroups are cyclic. That said, all _finite_ subgroups are cyclic!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61846/discussion-between-jevie-and-santana-afton).

Answer (score 2):

This will give a group and it will be the usual [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group). This is the group on the set $\{e^{i\phi}\mid \phi\in[0,2\pi)\}$ with complex multiplication as group operation. Alternatively it can be written as $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ as states in Evargalo's answer.

*Proof*.

Lets say the two points of the circle are given as $e^{i\phi}$ and $e^{i\psi}$. The corresponding line through the $1$ according to your description is given by

$$g(t)=1+t(e^{i\phi}-e^{i\psi}).$$

We are looking for the (if possible) non-zero value of $t$ for which $\|g(t)\|=1$. We can agree that there is at most one from the geometric intuition on this problem. So let me show you that

$$t^*=\frac{e^{i(\phi+\psi)}-1}{e^{i\phi}-e^{i\psi}}$$

is this value. This will give you $g(t^*)=e^{i(\phi+\psi)}=e^{i\phi}e^{i\psi}$. All we need to show is that $t^*$ is real. For this, multiply nominator and denominator with $e^{-1/2i\phi}e^{-1/2i\psi}$ to obtain

$$t^*=\frac
{e^{1/2i\phi}e^{1/2i\psi}-e^{-1/2i\phi}e^{-1/2i\psi}}
{e^{1/2i\phi}e^{-1/2i\psi}-e^{-1/2i\phi}e^{1/2i\psi}}.$$

Setting $z=e^{1/2i\phi}e^{1/2i\psi}$ and $w=e^{1/2i\phi}e^{-1/2i\psi}$ with their complex conjugates $\bar z$ and $\bar w$, we see that

$$t^*=\frac{z-\bar z}{w-\bar w}
=\frac{2i\cdot\mathrm{Im}(z)}{2i\cdot\mathrm{Im}(w)}
=\frac{\mathrm{Im}(z)}{\mathrm{Im}(w)}$$

which is real. $\;\square$

To be completely rigorous you will have to argue seperately for the case $t^*=\mathrm{Im}(z)=0$ and $\mathrm{Im}(w)=0$, but I hope this will do it for now.

---

I wrote a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349439/415941) motivated on this one, and you can see from the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2349461/415941) that no matter what you try, as soon as you develop a (topological) group structure on $S^1$, it will be the usual circle group structure.

Comment: Thank you for the proof and the links! I had a suspicion the groups were isomorphic, but I couldn't see the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the argument-modulus representation of the points of the circle (choosing the center of the circle as the origin and its radius as the unit), then:

$\mathcal{C}=\{e^{i\theta}, \theta\in[0,2\pi)\}$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{R}/2\pi$