# Topological groups on the circle $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, circles, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

On the circle $S^1$ there is the usual [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group), i.e. the group isomorphic to $\{e^{i\varphi}\mid \varphi\in[0,2\pi)\}$ with complex multiplication as group operation. This group is a *topological group* in the sense that $S^1$ is a topological space and the group operation and the inverse are continuous.

> **Question:** Are there other topological groups on $S^1$ essentially different from the circle group, assuming $S^1$ with the standard topology? What about other abelian topological groups?

My question was motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348338/415941) other post. The group described there turned out to be just the usual one.

Two notes:

- I am looking for groups involving all of $S^1$, not only a subset. Especially no subgroups of the circle group.
- I am looking for groups *not isomorphic* to the circle group.

Comment: Take any bijective homeomorphism $\varphi$ from $S^1$ to itself. This induces a new group structure given by $x\bullet y=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x)\varphi(y))$. A better question is whether there exist "essentially different" topological group structures - my gut feeling is that the answer to that question is no. Edited in: last edit to the question invalidates this comment, but I will keep it here for reference, I guess.

Comment: @Wojowu Ok, I specified I am looking for groups not isomorphic to the circle group.

Comment: The result that the group described in the linked question is isomorphic to the standard circle group is not-obvious and also not discussed there. Perhaps you could add your proof of that fact as an answer to the other question?

Comment: @Vincent Did so ;)

Comment: Good Q. BTW the lexicographic-order topology on $\mathbb R^2$ is a  topological group for at least two non-isomorphic groups : One  group operation is co-ordinate-wise addition. Another is $(x,y)\times (x',y')=(x+x',y+y'e^x),$ which is not  Abelian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a theorem that any two topological group structures on $S^1$ are isomorphic, and similarly for the $n$-torus $(S^1)^n$, $n \ge 1$: any compact topological group structure on the $n$-torus is isomorphic to the standard one.

Here is a high-powered proof by quoting two theorems.

One is the theorem quoted in Francesco Pollizi's answer to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67030/if-compact-connected-lie-groups-are-homeomorphic-as-topological-space-are-they): any compact abelian [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $(S^1)^n$.

The other theorem is [the solution to Hilbert's 5th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group#Hilbert.27s_fifth_problem) by Gleason, Montgomery, and Zippin: every topological group which is a manifold has a smooth structure which makes it a Lie group.

Now, my guess is that for the case of $S^1$ there is probably an elementary proof of this theorem, perhaps embedded somewhere as an example in the literature of topological groups, but I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

While Lee Mosher's answer is correct, it is an overkill. Suppose that $G$ is a topological group homeomorphic to $S^1$. Since $G$ is compact, you do not need to quote the solution of Hilbert-V: The [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) (which is much simpler) implies that each compact topological group admits a faithful finite dimensional  linear representation and, hence, is a Lie group (Cartan's theorem). Since the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ of $G$ is 1-dimensional, it is commutative. Hence $\exp: {\mathfrak g}={\mathbb R}\to G$ is a homomorphism (necessarily an epimorphism), hence, $G$ is isomorphic to $U(1)$.

Comment: Very nice, I've overlooked the Peter-Weyl theorem. But I do have a question. In the general case of a compact topological group, can you not also have a profinite group, or some inverse limit of Lie groups like the dynamic solenoid group (the inverse limit of $z \mapsto z^2$ acting on $S^1$)? If so, what condition on $G$ lets you get a Lie group on the nose?

Comment: @LeeMosher The point is that for connected groups each irreducible summand of a faithful representation has to have connected image.